# Parse: Merge existing user with facebook account

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, sdk

I have registered as normal signup with email *test@test.com*. Later I'm trying to login with Facebook with same email id *test@test.com*. This is creating new user in Parse.

How should I merge this Facebook User to the old account that have same email?

Answer (score 1):

Merging is probably going to be very difficult, because the 2 accounts have different login mechanisms. You would either need to delete one account and update all references to that user in the database or create your own 'user group' class so each user is associated with a group and that group represents the user. A group can have many users attached (the many logins for the individual e-mail address) and is used in all relationships where you would usually use the user.

Comment: Can't we update authData column while FB login if the email already present in parse.com?

Comment: You can try it, but I wouldn't expect it to be reliable long term if it does work as the auth data should be considered private parse data - best to ask them if it will work (long term)

Comment: OK. I'll post it in parse.com. Thanks.